# Firestore where clause with VueJS 2 data

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

In my app I need to get similar products to the one selected, so I have two methods for this:

```js
import firebase from "firebase";
import db from "../firebase/firebaseInit";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      carousel: this.$nextTick(() => (this.carousel = true)),
      interval: 6000,
      title: "",
      imgs: [],
      price: "",
      ref: "",
      desc: "",
      types: [],
      skin: "",
      colors: [],
      similars: [],
      tabs: [{
          id: 0,
          title: "Beskrivelse",
          text: this.desc
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "Rengøring",
          text: "Der er mange tilgængelige udgaver af Lorem Ipsum, men de fleste udgaver har gennemgået forandringer, når nogen har tilføjet humor eller tilfældige ord, som på ingen måde ser ægte ud."
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  metaInfo() {
    return {
      title: this.title
        .toString()
        .charAt(0)
        .toUpperCase() +
        this.title.slice(1) +
        " Urrem i " +
        this.skin
        .toString()
        .charAt(0)
        .toUpperCase() +
        this.skin.slice(1) +
        " " +
        this.ref,
      meta: [{
        name: "description",
        content: this.desc
          .toString()
          .charAt(0)
          .toUpperCase() + this.desc.slice(1)
      }]
    };
  },
  filters: {
    capitalize: function(value) {
      if (!value) return "";
      value = value.toString();
      return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
    }
  },
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    db.collection("straps")
      .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "==", to.params.id)
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          next(
            vm => (
              (vm.title = doc.data().title),
              (vm.price = doc.data().price),
              (vm.desc = doc.data().desc),
              (vm.skin = doc.data().skin),
              (vm.types = doc.data().types),
              (vm.imgs = doc.data().imgs),
              (vm.ref = doc.data().ref),
              (vm.colors = doc.data().colors)
            )
          );
        });
      });
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    db.collection("straps").where(
      firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),
      "==",
      to.params.id
    );
    onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        (this.id = doc.id),
        (this.title = doc.data().title),
        (this.price = doc.data().price),
        (this.desc = doc.data().desc),
        (this.skin = doc.data().skin),
        (this.types = doc.data().types),
        (this.imgs = doc.data().imgs),
        (this.colors = doc.data().colors);
      });
    });
    this.$nextTick(() => (this.carousel = true));
    next();
  },
  created() {
    this.getSimilar();
    this.fetchData();
  },
  watch: {
    $route: "fetchData"
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      db.collection("straps")
        .where(
          firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),
          "==",
          this.$route.params.id
        )
        .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            (this.id = doc.id),
            (this.title = doc.data().title),
            (this.price = doc.data().price),
            (this.desc = doc.data().desc),
            (this.skin = doc.data().skin),
            (this.types = doc.data().types),
            (this.imgs = doc.data().imgs),
            (this.colors = doc.data().colors);
          });
        });
    },
    getSimilar() {
      db.collection("straps")
        .where("skin", "==", this.skin)
        .orderBy("date", "desc")
        .limit(4)
        .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
          const similars = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const data = {
              id: doc.id,
              title: doc.data().title,
              skin: doc.data().skin,
              img: doc.data().imgs[0].url,
              price: doc.data().price,
              types: doc.data().types,
              date: doc
                .data()
                .date.toString()
                .slice(0, 15)
            };
            similars.push(data);
          });
          this.similars = similars;
        });
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-layout justify-center wrap>
      <v-flex xs12 sm10 lg8>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex>
            <v-layout class="strapinfotoside" justify-center wrap>
              <v-flex xs12 sm12>
                <v-container>
                  <v-layout>
                    <v-flex xs12>
                      <v-carousel :cycle="false" v-if="carousel" hide-controls class="elevation-0" :interval="interval">
                        <v-carousel-item v-for="img in imgs" :key="img.url" :src="img.url">
                        </v-carousel-item>
                      </v-carousel>
                    </v-flex>
                  </v-layout>
                </v-container>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs12 sm12 class="text-xs-left strapinfo">
                <v-flex>
                  <h1 class="titles">RIOS1931 {{this.types[0].title | capitalize}} {{this.title | capitalize}} Urrem i {{this.skin | capitalize}} {{this.ref}}</h1>
                  <p class="ref grey--text">Reference nr. {{this.ref | capitalize}}</p>
                  <p class="price mb-5">{{this.price | capitalize}} kr.</p>
                </v-flex>
                <!-- <v-flex sm6>
                                    <v-select :items="this.colors" label="Vælg farve" outline></v-select>
                                </v-flex> -->
                <v-flex>
                  <v-tabs color="grey darken-1" slider-color="primary">
                    <v-tab color="white--text" class="tab" v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.id" ripple>
                      {{tab.title}}
                    </v-tab>
                    <v-tab-item>
                      <v-card color="grey lighten-4" flat>
                        <v-card-text>
                          <p>{{ desc }}</p>
                          <h3 class="my-2"><strong>Produktdetaljer</strong></h3>
                          <p><strong>Fås i:</strong> <span class="colors" v-for="color in colors" :key="color.title">{{color.title | capitalize}}</span></p>
                          <p class="mt-2"><strong>Materiale:</strong> {{skin | capitalize}}</p>
                          <p><strong>Rem til:</strong> <span class="types" v-for="type in types" :key="type.title"> {{type.title | capitalize}}</span></p>
                          <p><strong>Materiale:</strong> {{skin | capitalize}}</p>
                        </v-card-text>
                      </v-card>
                    </v-tab-item>
                    <v-tab-item v-for="tab in tabs.slice(1,2)" :key="tab.id">
                      <v-card color="grey lighten-4" flat>
                        <v-card-text>{{ tab.text }}</v-card-text>
                      </v-card>
                    </v-tab-item>
                  </v-tabs>
                </v-flex>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
    <v-layout justify-center class="section">
      <v-flex xs12 sm10 lg9>
        <h2>Nyeste urremme</h2>
        <v-layout mt-3 justify-center wrap>
          <v-flex pa-3 xs6 sm3 lg2 v-for="similar in similars" :key="similar.id">
            <v-hover>
              <v-card :to="{name: 'Strap', params: {id: similar.id}}" flat slot-scope="{ hover }">
                <v-img :src="similar.img" aspect-ratio="1">
                  <v-layout slot="placeholder" fill-height align-center justify-center ma-0>
                    <v-progress-circular indeterminate color="black"></v-progress-circular>
                  </v-layout>
                </v-img>
                <v-card-title primary-title>
                  <h3 class="text-xs-left">RIOS1931 {{similar.title | capitalize}} Urrem i {{similar.skin | capitalize}}</h3>
                </v-card-title>
                <v-card-text style="padding: 0 !important;">
                  <p class="text-xs-left">{{similar.price}} kr.</p>
                </v-card-text>
              </v-card>
            </v-hover>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

My problem is that in the getSimilar() method, it won't get the products where the skin is equal to the selected products' skin with ".where("skin", "==", this.skin).

If I write console.log(this.skin) it returns the correct value.

Comment: So what do you get when running `getSimilar()`? Empty result, error, ...? Are you using any rules for the firebase db?

Comment: No security rules are preventing this from happening. When I write console.log(this.skin) I get the correct value, but it won't find the products with the .where("skin", "==" this.skin). If I write .where("skin", "==", "alligator") (Alligator is a similar product) I get the products.

Answer (score 0):

`.onSnapshot()` attaches a listener for QuerySnapshot events, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#onSnapshot

Therefore, I think it would be more appropriate to call it (or attach it) in the `created` life cycle hook as follows:

```
  methods: {
     .....
  },
  created: function() {
     db.collection("straps")
       .where("skin", "==", this.skin)
       .orderBy("date")
       .limit(4)
       .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
           ....
       });
       ...
     });
  }
```

If you want to fetch data in a method (i.e. in such a way that you call it on demand, i.e. by clicking a button) I would suggest you use the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get) method, as follows:

```
  getSimilar() {
    db.collection("straps")
      .where("skin", "==", this.skin)
      .orderBy("date")
      .limit(4)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        const similars = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const data = {
            id: doc.id,
            title: doc.data().title,
            skin: doc.data().skin,
            img: doc.data().imgs[0].url,
            price: doc.data().price,
            types: doc.data().types,
            date: doc
              .data()
              .date.toString()
              .slice(0, 15)
          };
          similars.push(data);
        });
        this.similars = similars;
        console.log(this.skin);
      });
  }
```

Comment: I tried the .get().then() but it still doesn't show the desired products with similar skintype. Putting it in created doesn't help

Comment: Can you check if the querySnapshot is empty or not? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot

Comment: You are sure that this.skin has a value **inside** the getSimilar() method?

Comment: Also, double check that this.similars = similars; does what it is supposed to do. Normally there should not be any problem of scope since you use an arrow function but better to double check with a console.log on similars first and then on this.similars after the line is executed..

Comment: When I write console.log(this.skin) I get the correct value, but it won't find the products with the .where("skin", "==" this.skin). If I write .where("skin", "==", "alligator") (Alligator is a similar product) I get the similar products

Comment: That seems crazy! Can you share the entire code of your component (in particular the data object)? Just add it to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182250/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-fred).

Comment: I saw your print screens, thanks. Could you add a `console.log` at the top of the function, like `getSimilar() {console.log(this.skin); db.collection("straps")...`

Comment: I named them First and Second, where the first one above the db.collection... doesn't show any value, but the second one does

Comment: changing this.getsimilar() to be below this.fetchData() in created didn't help

Comment: If I am not mistaking it appears that you are setting the value of this.skin through some asynchronous calls to the Firebase database. Most probably the value is not returned from Firebase when you execute `getSimilar()`. You should chain your asynchronous events correctly.

Comment: @Fred Hi any progress on that on your side?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this question hasn't been answered